# variable assigned in conditional is used in same conditional, throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if user = User.find_by(email: 'example@example.com') && !user.activated?
    # do something
end
```

but I get an error thrown saying "no method 'activated' for nil:NilClass"

Is there a way for me to accomplish this functionality without using a nested conditional?

Comment: Are you sure that is exactly what your code looks like? I believe that should work because if the user isn't found then it'll return nil which will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the control flow operator `and` over the logical operator `&&` like so:

```
  if user = User.find_by(email: 'example@example.com') and !user.activated?
    # do something
  end
```

**Example:**

```
if a = 12 && a.even? 
  "Working"
end 
#=> undefined method `even?' for nil:NilClass
if b = 12 and b.even? 
  "Working"
end 
#=> "Working"
```

This works because `and` has a lower precedent than assignment so the assignment will occur prior to the second conditional check.

As long as you don't mind the `found = in conditional, should be ==` warnings.

**Second Option:**

Your other option is explicit parentheses ie.

```
if a = 12 && a.even? 
  "Working"
end 
#=> undefined method `even?' for nil:NilClass
if (b = 12) && b.even? 
  "Working"
end 
#=> "Working"
```

This works because the parentheses `()` will be evaluated first before the conditional is evaluated so the assignment will occur inside the parens and then be evaluated as part of the conditional.

[More on Ruby Operator Precedence](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence)

Comment: 2.2.0 :001 > puts "opopo" if user = "xxx" && !user.nil?
 => nil 
2.2.0 :002 > puts "opopo" if user = "xxx" and !user.nil?
(irb):2: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
opopo
 => nil 
Not the recommended way as per the IRB concerns. Rest you can do what ever you like boss.

Comment: @MuaazRafi I am well aware but the question was asked and this is the appropriate answer. Sometimes control flow makes sense even when warnings are present take for example something like `send_email_message if user = User.find_by(conditions) and user.email_opt_in?` this will work and will only send the email if the user has opted in.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, You can not assign and use the same var in same line, you will need to break it up.

```
user = User.find_by(email: 'example@example.com')

if user && !user.activated?
    # do something
end
```

Let me know if this helps. You can check user.nil? but above will work as well.

Comment: Declare the variable above and use that reference save memory

Comment: 2.2.0 :001 > puts "opopo" if user = "xxx" && !user.nil?
 => nil 
2.2.0 :002 > puts "opopo" if user = "xxx" and !user.nil?
(irb):2: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
opopo
 => nil

Not the recommended way as per irb :P

Comment: Not good practice to declare vars in your if conditions you can check the manual. (irb):2: warning: found = in conditional as you can see rest you can do whatever you like boss.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the case when a user is not found. You should add exception handling in condition:

```
if user = User.find_by(email: 'example@example.com') && !user.try(:activated)?
    # do something
end
```

Comment: This will not work as it will always be false because `NilClass` will not have the activated method and assignment will not have occurred prior to the second conditional check.

Comment: it will only come to second part of statement after executing the find query first